# bundler Rails require different gem in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to set up a develoment environment for developing a Rails gem.  I would like to load the gem from a local source in development mode and via rubygems in production.  I would like to do something like the following:

#### Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'my_gem', '1.0.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'my_gem', :path => '~/apps/my_gem'
end
```

When I run the `bundle` command, bundler complains that you can't load the same gem twice.  Is there a way to require different versions of a gem depending on the Rails environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Doing this defeats the purpose of using Bundler**. The whole point is that the dependencies you're using are consistent no matter where your application is loaded, deliberately trying to circumvent that goal is just going to cause you problems.

What happens when your local version of that gem is different than the one released in Rubygems (perhaps because you forgot to release a new version?)? Your app may blow up and you won't be able to reproduce it in development, which is *horrible*.

As for why this isn't even conceivable to achieve with Bundler (at least now): what happens if the dependency versions for the Gem are different in the Rubygems version vs. the local version are different? Now your entire Gemfile.lock needs to have two completely different dependency graphs, and you're potentially introducing countless more points of failure in production that wouldn't exist in development.

That said, it's okay to *temporarily* change your Gemfile to the local version while making changes to the gem, but you should change it back and release a new version of the gem, then `bundle update my_gem` to update the Gemfile.lock accordingly.

Comment: I've been trying to speed up my development process for Rails gems and constantly editing the Gemfile was a step I wanted to eliminate.  I realize now after reading your answer why bundler doesn't provide this behavior.  I guess I didn't think that one through and I'm just going to have to live with that step.  Thanks for the thoughtful response.

Comment: That's alright. I understand your motivation for wanting to do so. Also note that you can point Bundler to use a Git repo for a gem, which can also be useful.

Comment: Sure, but I have a problem with a gem we develop.  In development I want bundler to update from the locally installed gems, to grab the latest one, but production should get it from github to only get merged versions.  I really don't want two version dependencies in the Gemfile or two line, but I do want a conditional to use the :git option only for production.  I think OP was doing something similar where production should only use the gem repo.

Comment: Basically I'm entirely on board that you want one statement of the version range boundaries, to keep development lockstep with production.  You should check in the new range for production when the code changed in development which needs the change is checked in.  However, bundler has many Gemfile features about where to get the code, and production might differ from development, by being restricted only to official vetted sources, such as a gem server or git repo server.

Answer (score 23):

I've had the same problem and solved like this:

```
if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "development"
  gem 'my_gem', :path => '~/apps/my_gem'
else
  gem 'my_gem', '1.0.0'
end
```

then you can run `RAILS_ENV=development bundle` on your local machine and run any environment related command through `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec`

Comment: I like this solution, you could even add `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'` to default to development.  I may select this as the right answer.

Comment: Note that this won't work on Heroku, as Heroku can't handle conditionals in your Gemfile.

Answer (score -5):

it's probably that you have put  gem 'my_gem' in somewhere else also, double check it